# OpenGL - rotate own vision?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I'm trying to work on some OpenGL stuff. What I've got up to now is a viewport, in which I'm drawing some imaginary "borders" by using GL_LINES. It looks like this, with `setLookAt` set as follows:

`Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);`

[image]

My frustum is set: `Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -2, 2, -2, 2, 1, 11);` so I'm positioned somewhere inside the "cube".

Now what I'm trying to achieve is let the user look around. I'm capturing onTouchEvents, passing any movement in x/y direction to the renderer. What I'm doing next is rotating all lines drawn by the specific angle I received from the touch listener.

It then looks like this:

[image]

So the cube is not rotated around the viewer or the eye-center, but instead around some point that I don't know where it's coming from.

My problem is: how can I rotate the object around the viewer's center/position? Do I have to rotate the `mViewMatrix` which comes from setLookAtM? If yes, simply by using `Matrix.setRotateM(mViewMatrix, ...)`?

The Line's drawing method looks like this:

```
  public void draw(float[] mViewMatrix, float[] mProjectionMatrix) {
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
    lineBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, lineBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);

    colorBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iColor, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iColor);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, rotX, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -rotY, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    //GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(iVPMatrix, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(iVPMatrix, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);


    //GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_LINES, mVertices.length/2, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, mVertices.length / 2);
}
```

Comment: If you want to "look around" you should rotate your view matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at function takes 3 vertices, eye position, target position and up vector. Basically it generates a matrix that moves scene around to render scene like you are looking from eye position to target position. In your example your is at 0,0,0 and looks at 5, 0, 0 (so you are looking at +x direction and up is defined as 0, 1, 0 (higher y value means object will be at top of window.)

Instead of using those constants, first define a camera position.

```
float cameraX, cameraY, cameraY;
```

it is harder to work with target vectors, so instead use an angle that defines which direction you are looking at

```
float angle;
```

and to calculate targetVector use this angle.

```
float targetX = cameraX + cos(angle);
float targetY = cameraY;
float targetZ = cameraZ + sin(angle);
```

Now to move camera around, you have to modify cameraX-Y-Z. If you want to move forward you should move your camera towards to target vector. For example to move 10 unit forward.

```
targetX += cos(angle)*10;
targetY += sin(angle)*10;
```

You also need to recalculate target vector since target position also should move.

If you want to move backwards, use -= operator instead. If you want to move sides then you have to add or remove angle PI/2 in those calculations.

To rotate camera around just increase/decrease angle and recalculate target vector.

This is a very basic camera and you won't be able to look up or down. You have to use pitch/yaw camera to be able to look up and down.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I kind of can't get it to work properly. In my onTouch method, I adapted it to give me a single angle (at first it was the position-difference): ACTION_DOWN: save X/Y position, ACTION_MOVE: angle = atan2(newX - oldX, newY - oldY); and tried to adapt your snippet with +cos(angle) and +sin(angle), but the values where way to high, it immediately went up to +1000 or something, and the rotation was stuck. At the moment I don't know how I should move the target vector depending on the touch movement on screen..